# Netezza Sequence error

Tags: netezza, ibm-netezza-administrator

I am new to Netezza and have a quick question.

I do a simple select of next val from sequence

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR XX.XX.RUN_SEQ FROM _V_DUAL I
```

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Sequence 46339885 not properly initialized

I get the above error, can some one help?

DDL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE XX.RUN_SEQ AS BIGINT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE 
    NO MAXVALUE 
    NO CYCLE;
```